# How to make python wait for the exact amount of time taken to upload certain number of files?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, upload, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working with python for only a couple of months. I have a list of files I want to upload using Selenium and Python. Here is the code:

```
for k in os.listdir('../Uploads'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(k, '*.pdf'):
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('@xpath').send_keys(os.path.abspath("../Uploads" + "\\" + k))
```

However, with the new update of Chrome (77) and chromedriver, python doesn't wait for a file to be uploaded and moves on to the rest of the code instantly. I added `time.sleep(10)` after the `for...` loop. Python then waited for 10 secs for all the files in the directory to upload, which may or may not be sufficient for all the uploads, depending on the file sizes and number of files.

I also tried:

```
for k in os.listdir('../Uploads'):
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(k, '*.pdf'):
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'@xpath'))).send_keys(os.path.abspath("../Uploads"+"\\"+k))
```

but python waited for `10 secs` and gave a timeout error without uploading any file.

Please suggest a way around this.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a change in the DOM after a file gets uploaded? For example the file name gets displayed somewhere? If thats the case, you can do an implicit wait for each one of the file to be displayed there and continue only after that happens for every file

Comment: @eduardoreynoso that worked, easy and efficient. Thank you so much!